# How to execute jquery instance twice for Bootstrap 3 Carousel?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel which slides one by one.
I want to have 2 sliders at the same time on my page. But I think it conflicts with each other.
what is the best practice to resolve this issue?

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12"><h3>Bootstrap 3 Multiple Slide Carousel</h3></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -25%; }
.carousel-control            { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:15px;background-image:none;}
```

JQUERY

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

Link : http://www.bootply.com/G8paYJb4N9

Answer (score 3):

According to [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) you can, but you must ensure that each carousel's controls target the right carousel through its id. 
For example, you can have #myCarousel1 and #myCarousel2, and all the controls for the first carousel will target #myCarousel1 like this:

```
[...]   
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
[...]
```